# Compare database to master template database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to be able to compare a database against a master or template database. If there are columns that don't exist in the database being compared, then the script should add the columns to table it's missing from.

I'm not real sure where to start but I have this:

```
USE [database_that_needs_to_be_compared]

SELECT 
    TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME
    ,DATA_TYPE
    ,CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
    ,IS_NULLABLE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME ASC
```

This will give me all the information that I think I need from my database that needs to be updated or checked. My thought was that I could do a join of some sort but again, not really sure where to start.

Comment: While you *can* write this sort of stuff from scratch, it's much more productive to use existing tooling (e.g. Redgate's SQL compare and Microsoft's own [SqlPackage](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/tools/sqlpackage) / schema compare tool in VS), especially if the intent is to generate scripts afterwards to synchronize them, which is highly nontrivial to do from T-SQL.

Comment: do you have to do this purely using scripts or can you use a ready-made tool? e.g. see this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/how-to-use-schema-compare-to-compare-different-database-definitions?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I'm trying to incorporate this process as another step in an existing Powershell script to add columns, if needed, during an upgrade of a customers program. I'm not sure how I could use the mentioned tools to accomplish this.

Comment: Those tools would generate SQL scripts that can be applied to the target database, and they support command-line invocation, so you could generate migration scripts and execute them at your leisure. If you include versioning information in your DB, you could select the correct migration scripts based on that. Database projects and `SqlPackage` are pretty much designed for exactly this scenario. Even outside T-SQL, correctly generating scripts for migration is a chore (I'm speaking from practical experience), so these things do help.

Comment: Sounds convincing. I will take a look at the SQLPackage.exe. Any tricks or caveats I should know about?

Comment: One major one -- AFAIK you can't distribute `SqlPackage` freely, if you wanted to perform the migration check and script generation on the customer machine itself (i.e. you can't prepare it offline because the customer is free to change the database themselves). The same functionality is available programmatically via the `Microsoft.SqlServer.DacFx.*` NuGet packages, but those also do not technically allow distribution according to the license (I think). You could do the installation on the fly from MS sources, of course, but that may not be desirable for the customer. That said, IANAL.

Comment: I don't think that will be an issue. We host all of the databases, so any changes to the databases are done server side. Did I understand that correctly?

Comment: Yes, if you host the databases and control the machines they're on there's obviously no issue running DB compare tools from within your own company (hence no need to distribute anything).

Answer (score 0):

you can use a `LEFT JOIN` from your `master_template_database` to the `database_that_needs_to_be_compared`

```
SELECT  *
FROM    [master_template_database].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS m
LEFT JOIN [database_that_needs_to_be_compared].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
ON      m.TABLE_NAME  = c.TABLE_NAME
AND     m.COLUMN_NAME = c.COLUMN_NAME
```

Add the condition you required in `WHERE` clause

if there are possibly column that added to the `database_that_needs_to_be_compared` but not in `master_template_database` then you will need to use `FULL OUTER JOIN` to identify